# Disable cursor precision in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, compiz, touchpad, unity8

I have a question (I'm full of those today...) and would like help. I have used Unity8 on my Netbook, and I noticed that the cursor has no dynamic speed control, similar to when you disable "Increased Pointer Precision" in Windows. I like how moving on the touchpad will make the cursor fly across the screen (don't ask, I don't know why), and would like to replicate it in Unity (and later Gnome Flashback Compiz).

Comment: Hee hee! As far as I know, you're the only one who likes it. The developers of the mouse drivers might not have thought to implement such a feature. ;)

Comment: XD Haha I know, right! The one place windows beat ubuntu. I just like it because it's different. I like things different, well and it's easier to play minecraft on the bus that way ;P